# LINQ to SQL query Multiply two columns and calculate SUM

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

Here's the SQL query

```
Select sum(f.Acres*m.credit1), sum(f.Acres*m.credit2), sum(f.Acres*m.credit3)
from first f join model m on f.Id = m.fID
where m.year == 2012
```

How to write this above SQL in LINQ?

Thanks!

Comment: 4th hit on Google.. http://download.damieng.com/dotnet/LINQToSQLCheatSheet.pdf (PDF by the way)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However I am having difficulty with multiplying and then computing the sum. Multiplication has to be done from two different tables in the join and I am not sure how to do tht.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little tricky to do in Linq since you need a group to be able to do aggregates. By grouping on a dummy value like below it'll work:

```
var q = from f in first
        join m in model on f.Id equals m.fID
        where m.year == 2012
        group new { f, m } by 1 into g
        select new 
        { 
           credit1 = g.Sum(x => x.f.Acres * x.m.credit1),
           credit2 = g.Sum(x => x.f.Acres * x.m.credit2),
           credit3 = g.Sum(x => x.f.Acres * x.m.credit3)
        };
```

**EDIT**
From reading your comments.
If you want it group per year, this is how you do it:

```
var q = from f in first
        join m in model on f.Id equals m.fID
        where m.year >= 2014 && m.year <= 2020
        group new { f, m } by m.year into g
        select new 
        { 
           year    = g.Key,
           credit1 = g.Sum(x => x.f.Acres * x.m.credit1),
           credit2 = g.Sum(x => x.f.Acres * x.m.credit2),
           credit3 = g.Sum(x => x.f.Acres * x.m.credit3)
        };
```

Comment: Thanks! I am able to get the desired results now. I have one more question.

Comment: Thanks very much. I am able to get the desired results now. I have one more question. If I change the query to include a range of years, instead of 1 year, then how do I compute sum values for each year. The query above calculates the whole sum. New query is from f in first
        join m in model on f.Id equals m.fID
        where m.year >= 2014 and m.year <= 2020
        group new { f, m } by 1 into g
        select new ....same as above

Comment: @Veena Updated the answer with your additional question.

Comment: In the above query, how do I retrieve other column values of first and model tables..just the values stored in the database..say if first table has col1, col2, col3..how can i access those values inside select? Thanks much for your help.

Comment: @Veena You can only access them inside an aggregate or if you add them to the group by (just like in SQL)